# OAuthException 1 while posting image to facebook by calling /me/photos api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the permission for user_photos as well publish_actions for my app for uploading photos to user facebook wall.After the user gets logged in my app is enable to publish photo to user timeline.I am calling /me/photos api for uploading photo after getting the user authResponse.some days before I can able to post photo to user timeline.but suddenly it stopped working by giving the below exception to my code.

code    1
message "An unknown error has occurred."
type "OAuthException"

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can confirm this bug (or API deprecation?), in my particular case, I've  had an Facebook app running with those two same permissions three months ago like a charm. As of today, the upload is being made to the app album, but it returns the same error code Smita mentioned, hence I can't retrieve the photo id for further use.

Comment: can anyone got the same issue and able to solve this?

Comment: The issue was with the image url.In our case image url contains "https" as its scheme name due to which it was showing the Unknown Exception.so by changing the scheme to "http" resolved the issue.